# Responsive design using Dreamweaver and help to find another program than Dw

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver, but now I am thinking about trying another program. I am kind of new to html and css, but I feel I have kind of control using html and css3. Now I am learning how to creative responsive webdesign using bootstrap.

Might be a stupid and simple question; When I want to create a new html page, I can choose "create a responsive page using Boostrap". If I just select html and makes a css sheet, will I still be able to make a responsive design? Thinking about using "insert" and then choose "Bootstrap Components".

I have made pages with bootstrap templates now. It's ok and I am managing to style the template. Still I feel more comfortable making it from scratch. I feel I am learning more and have more control doing it this way.

--

I guess I should just stick to Dw, but I want to learn more. I am kind of a learning-by-doing-girl and want to try out another program. I like the ability to use "Show code and design" in Dw, so a program with this included would be great.

Which programs have this capability?

I have downloaded Atom, and I know you can refresh the website to see the result, but that means I have to connect the site to a server? Right now I don't want to connect the site to a server of different reasons.

Comment: This is off-topic, but what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using  Windows 8.1

Comment: I would also suggest Atom or Sublime. I personally like Espresso, but it is Mac only.

Answer (score 1):

You should try out a standard text editor like Sublime Text or Atom. Do your code editing there and open your page in the browser. Refresh to see changes as you make them.

Answer (score 0):

I like Notepad++.

The problem with programs like DreamWeaver is that they can instill some pretty bad habits in novices. You are absolutely right in wanting to learn without it first.

The reason I like Notepad++ is that it has great code highlighting, one of the things I think draws people in to DW, too.